# Is there a 64bit version of Qmaster

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

I just noticed that all of the qmaster stuff on my mac is 32 bit. Software update doesn't have any information about newer versions though. Was this package dropped by Apple or are there 64 bit versions that I can download somewhere?